# Windows XP Network Drive - Disconnected Upon Login

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

I have two network drives mapped (`S:` and `U:`).  When I first log into Windows their type shows as "Disconnected Network Drive".  How can I get them to to connect automatically?

**More Info**

They connect as soon as I access them in Windows Explorer.  The reason that I even noticed is that when I open Dreamweaver or Netbeans IDE, they do not initiate the connection and are unable to see the files in those mapped drives.  I have made a habit of opening Windows Explorer and browsing the drives as soon as I log in. It's annoying to have to do that, which led me to post this question.

Comment: Are you able to access the drives by double-clicking them (in My Computer) or are they inaccessible? Where I work I frequently encounter the same situation but I have no difficulty accessing the drives.

Comment: Yes, I can access them by clicking them, they are not inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that when the drives were loaded, that it could not access them.  This could be because someone is offsite, and not on the VPN, or that the drives are mapped by a system logon script or something, which happens before a user logon. (also a group policy tied to the machine)

It really doesn't make much difference, you can just click on them later and they will update, it just does not poll the drives, as that would really increase network traffic.  It looks and sounds bad, but everything should be fine.

Comment: I updated my post.  It's not "bad", but creates a minor annoyance.

Comment: @sonny, did you map them manually, and tell them to reconnect at login, or is it done via another way, such as GPO or logon scripts?

Comment: I mapped them manually.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer, even though I never solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Reconnect at logon box checked?  It's basically the same as the `/persistent:yes` flag with `net use`.  Only problem is it can lock up Explorer if the computer can't find the server, so it might be a good thing that it starts as disconnected.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that box was checked when creating the mapped drive.

Comment: If the computer can't find the server after a matter of time (not sure how long), it'll mark the drive as disconnected.  If it doesn't, Explorer will hang trying to find it every time it comes across it.